# Retrieving multiple string values from localstorage in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, local-storage

I am attempting to pull a string of data from localstorage in javascript and combine multiple values from multiple strings. For example
I may have the following 2 strings

```
Bob;companyA;6141692120;email1@email.com;1 John St;;Bellevue;6056;;6;10;20.00;52.800000000000004;72.80;7.28;80.08;
Jane;companyB;6157692120;email2@email.com;1 Jack St;;Bellevue;6056;;6;10;20.00;52.800000000000004;72.80;7.28;80.08;
```

I want to ignore the first few and add the last 5 or 6 together from each, so value [13] in string A + value [13] in string B = X, there will be doens of strings and they all have random numbers, I have attached the javascript code below and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

```
windows.onload= getAllItems();
function getAllItems(){

var all = [];
for(var i = 0, j = localStorage.length; i < j; i++) {
    all[i] = localStorage[i].split(';');
}

var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0, j = all.length; i < j; i++) {
    sum += all[i][12];
}

var bags = all[9];
var distance = all[10];
var hdelivery_fee = all[11];
var hprice = all[12];
var htotal_notax = all[13];
var hgst = all[14];
var htotal_tax = all[15];
var hordernumber  = all[16];

document.write('Number of Bags; ' + bags + '<br />');
document.write('Distance; ' + distance + '<br />');
document.write('Delivery Fee; $' + hdelivery_fee + '<br />');
document.write('Price of Bags; $' + hprice + '<br />');
document.write('Total Ex-GST; $' + htotal_notax + '<br />');
document.write('GST; $' + hgst + '<br />');
document.write('Total Inc GST; $' + htotal_tax + '<br />');
document.write('hordernumber; ' + hordernumber + '<br />');
}
```

Also it is probably worth mentioning that this is an assignment and as such I am not allowed to use JSON or jquery in any capacity

EDIT: I have changed the code to match the answer given below, and I think i have taken the output out of the loop, however I am incredibly new at this so a lot of it is hit and miss. It doesnt seem to be working as is even though it looks like it should (to me)

EDIT2: Adding javascript for localstorage info source

```
function source()
{
var newDate = new Date();
var itemId = newDate.getTime();
var values = new Array();
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var company = document.getElementById("company").value;
    var contactnumber= document.getElementById("contactnumber").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var address1 = document.getElementById("address1").value;
    var address2 = document.getElementById("address2").value;
    var suburb = document.getElementById("suburb").value;
    var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
    var comments = document.getElementById("comments").value;
    var bags = document.getElementById("bags").value;
    var distance = document.getElementById("distance").value;
    var hdelivery_fee = document.getElementById("hdelivery_fee").value;
    var hprice = document.getElementById("hprice").value;
    var htotal_notax = document.getElementById("htotal_notax").value;
    var hgst = document.getElementById("hgst").value;
    var htotal_tax= document.getElementById("htotal_tax").value;
    var hordernumber= document.getElementById("hordernumber").value;


values.push(name);
values.push(company);
values.push(contactnumber);
values.push(email);
values.push(address1);
values.push(address2);
values.push(suburb);
values.push(postcode);
values.push(comments);
values.push(bags);
values.push(distance);
values.push(hdelivery_fee);
values.push(hprice);
values.push(htotal_notax);
values.push(hgst);
values.push(htotal_tax);
values.push(hordernumber);

try {
    localStorage.setItem(itemId, values.join(";")); 
} catch (e) {
    if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
        alert("Quota exceeded!");
    }
}

}
```

EDIT3:

adding entire html page for location of report including javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Processor</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">




</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
        <h1 id="main_tile"> Everwarm Fuel Merchants - Daily Report </h1>

    </div>
<h1> Daily Sales Summary <h1>

<p>
<script>
function getAllItems(){
    var all=[];
    for (i = 0,j=localStorage.length; i<j; i++) {
        all[i] = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)).split(';');
    }
    function getTotal(index) {
         var sum = 0;
         for(var i = 0, j = all.length; i < j; i++) {
            sum += parseFloat(all[i][index]);
        }
        return sum;
    }
    var bags = getTotal(9);
    var distance = getTotal(10);
    var hdelivery_fee = getTotal(11);
    var hprice = getTotal(12);
    var htotal_notax = getTotal(13);
    var hgst = getTotal(14);
    var htotal_tax = getTotal(15);
    var hordernumber = getTotal(16);

    document.write('Number of Bags; ' + bags + '<br />');
    document.write('Distance; ' + distance + '<br />');
    document.write('Delivery Fee; $' + hdelivery_fee + '<br />');
    document.write('Price of Bags; $' + hprice + '<br />');
    document.write('Total Ex-GST; $' + htotal_notax + '<br />');
    document.write('GST; $' + hgst + '<br />');
    document.write('Total Inc GST; $' + htotal_tax + '<br />');
    document.write('hordernumber; ' + hordernumber + '<br />');
  }</script>

  </p>


<input type="button" value="Clear storage" onclick="localstorage.clear()" > </input>

<input type="button" value="Return" onclick="history.back()"> </input>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for being open about this being coursework.

Comment: You shouldn't be allowed to use `document.write` either

Comment: hehe, i think the use of `document.write` is the first indication of a newbie

Comment: By the way, what's your question?

Comment: i am trying to add values from different strings and display them, it is supposed to be a report of some kind for displaying the days taking, tax etc, and because I cant use a server of any kind, localstorage is my only option. So i am trying to take say value [13] from strings A, B, C etc and get the sum total and display it on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution uses a loop that includes all the process - even the output!
You need to separate the process in two. The loop part would pick up all the data and add it all up, then the output part doesn't need a loop.

Try this:

```
function getAllItems(){
    var all=[];
    for (i = 0,j=localStorage.length; i<j; i++) {
        all[i] = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)).split(';');
    }
    function getTotal(index) {
         var sum = 0;
         for(var i = 0, j = all.length; i < j; i++) {
            sum += parseFloat(all[i][index]);
        }
        return sum;
    }
    var bags = getTotal(9);
    var distance = getTotal(10);
    var hdelivery_fee = getTotal(11);
    var hprice = getTotal(12);
    var htotal_notax = getTotal(13);
    var hgst = getTotal(14);
    var htotal_tax = getTotal(15);
    var hordernumber = getTotal(16);

    document.write('Number of Bags; ' + bags + '<br />');
    document.write('Distance; ' + distance + '<br />');
    document.write('Delivery Fee; $' + hdelivery_fee + '<br />');
    document.write('Price of Bags; $' + hprice + '<br />');
    document.write('Total Ex-GST; $' + htotal_notax + '<br />');
    document.write('GST; $' + hgst + '<br />');
    document.write('Total Inc GST; $' + htotal_tax + '<br />');
    document.write('hordernumber; ' + hordernumber + '<br />');
  }
```

Comment: ok, thanks for that. It all seems to make sense, I am just having trouble putting that into the context of my code. With my original code I had some sort of display on the html that referenced this, now when i replace everything between lines 3 and 13 with the above, I dont get an output. Am i doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: hey, thanks for the replies, please excuse my gross incompetence but I am having trouble getting the output now, I should be still be to use `var hprice = all[12];` and `document.write('Price of Bags; $' + hprice + '<br />');` to output the data shouldnt I?

Comment: Well for one thing you're writing out the results of the calculation while still calculating inside the for loop. You need to gather the results within the loop and then document.write outside the loop. And why are you subtracting 1 from the storage length in `var logLength = localStorage.length - 1;` ?

Comment: i have updated the code in the original question to match what i think everything should be, I believe the calculations are no longer in the loop and the logLength has been replaced by the variables you have provided. Please let me know.

Comment: with that one, I am getting the following error in chromes dev tools,  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined**

I have confirmed there are multiple strings available in localstorage and have copied and pasted directly from here, I think im cursed as it still isnt working!! :-(

Comment: try using localStorage.key(i). It would help to see how localStorage is being loaded.

Comment: I have added the javascript to the question above, it contains everythig i sue to get the data. It is contained in a standard form with text, number and date inputs as well as a few hidden text values to help add the totals up for each sale

Comment: Ok try my latest revision. Sorry about that, it was my bad.

Comment: hey, you dont need to apologise to me mate, i appreciate your help more than i can express in a textbox. In saying that i put the latest revision into the html page and it still isnt working. I have attached the entire page and have added the javascript in rather than having it external, I cannot see why it shouldnt work.

Comment: Are you sure there is any data in localStorage? try `console.log(localStorage)` and see what you get. If you have chrome, right click the page and select 'Inspect Element'. Then go to the console tab.

Comment: yeah there is definatley data there, on the plus side, i cant see any errors, the one from before has gone :-)

Comment: ok well i need to see that data in order to know what's going on. can you post it on jsfiddle?

Comment: ok i figured it out, just accounted for empty values. check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/J7zKF/